# How to use application context to mock flask request

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, request

I am trying to properly unit test my `Flask 1.1.2` routes, but do not really understand the documentation around mocking the application context.

Here is my class `Launch.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from LaunchHelper import runController

#Create app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/write-database',methods=['POST'])
def writeDatabase():
  return runController(request)
```

Here is my new `TestLaunch.py` after following the comment of @Felipe Emirem:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from flask import request #added
from Launch import app #added

class TestLaunch(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('Launch.runController')
  def test_writeDatabase(self,runController):

    resp = MagicMock()
    runController.return_value = resp

    with app.test_client() as c:
        ret = c.post('/write-database')

        #assert ret == resp
        runController.assert_called_with(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

I can now assert that `runController` was called with `flask.request` by importing the `app` directly from `Launch.py`, which makes sense. But I am not sure how to confirm that the response is returning correctly.

Additionally I am now getting the following error:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /write-database [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
  return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2117, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\base_response.py", line 269, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\base_response.py", line 26, in _run_wsgi_app
return app_iter, response[0], Headers(response[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Even though the test is passing.

*Edit: Here is my old test class `TestLaunch.py` before I changed to use `app.test_context()`:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from Launch import writeDatabase

class TestLaunch(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('Launch.runController')
  @patch('Launch.request')
  def test_writeDatabase(self,request,runController):

    resp = MagicMock()
    runController.return_value = resp

    ret = writeDatabase()

    assert ret == resp
    runController.assert_called_with(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

I ran this on older versions of flask, and it worked fine, but now I am getting `Working out of request context` error due to the `@patch('Launch.request')` line. I have tried to read through other stackoverflow posts and the flask documentation, but I can't really find anything that applies to my current use case.

Comment: What you are doing seems very different from what is described [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/). Try creating an app client and making an actual request to your controller.

Comment: I followed the documentation and now have it much closer to testing what I need. The only problem is now I am not sure how to test that the `resp` is being returned from `runController`.

Comment: If you did something like this: `data = self.client.post('yourParameters')`, then `data` contains the response for your request. I have some testing examples [here](https://gitlab.com/lip.emerim/post-api/-/tree/master/test/test_blueprint), although I am testing JSON responses, they may help you. The docs also have an [example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#test-adding-messages) where they test if certain messages are contained in the response. For me to help you more I would need your updated code.

Comment: I did edit to reflect my updated code, but I am now getting a new error message, even though my test continues to pass. Additionally, If I try and query the `ret` I get a `500 Internal Server` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Just needed to use the `test_request_context` which I read about here: [link](https://diegoquintanav.github.io/flask-contexts.html).

Here is my new `TestLaunch.py`:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from flask import request
from Launch import app, writeDatabase

class TestLaunch(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('Launch.runController')
  def test_writeDatabase(self,runController):
    resp = MagicMock()
    runController.return_value = resp

    with app.test_request_context() as c:
        ret = writeDatabase()

    assert ret == resp
    runController.assert_called_with(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

I am not testing the URL (which I wasn't originally anyway), but I am able to test that the `flask request` object is being handled properly.